# How to split the label in R for a plot

Tags: r, rpart

I am trying to plot CART model that I have built,the node label is too long and want to split it into two lines. I have used gsub() to split it but I want to split the next line too.

here is the code.

```
model=rpart(Train$service_date_max_count~ injury_type_cd+specialty_type_cd
            +state+age+sex+pedestrian_yn+vehicle_driver_yn+vehicle_passenger_yn
            +marital_status+category+extesio, data=Train,method ="anova")


split.fun <- function(x, labs, digits, varlen, faclen)
{
  gsub(" = ", ":\n", labs)
}

fancyRpartPlot(model , palettes = 'Oranges' ,tweak =0.8, split.fun=split.fun)
```

I have attached a snippet showing how the plot looks[image: TREE]

Comment: Please provide your model object with `dput(model)` and the packages you've used so we can reproduce your plot.